# ADOMD connection to SSAS

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssas, adomd.net

I tried to connect my c# app to the SQL Server Analysis Services server, to execute some MDX query.
The connection is done as follows :

```
      try{
            string connetionString;
            connetionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Catalog=SalesCubeDB;";
            
            AdomdConnection cnn;
            cnn = new AdomdConnection(connetionString);
            cnn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection established !!");
        
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

This connection throws the following error :

```
AdomdConnectionException: A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running
```

I tried Servername instead of 'localhost', I added rules in the firewall for the traffic and also made sure that the Server Browser uses 'Local System'. If somebody has any ideas i will be grateful, THANKS.

Environment : Windows 10 VM, SQL server 19, ADOMD version 19.26.1.2

Comment: Try "Data Source=(local)"

Comment: @squillman the same issue

Comment: Your app is running on the same machine as the SQL Server?  It almost sounds like your app is running on your _host_ machine and your SQL Server is running in the guest VM?

Comment: Actually, both are running on the VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue and this answer to everyone who might stumble on the same issue.
The client app is a console app, so I added the following packages :

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting
```

I also added the following to the Connection String (I use Windows authentification) :

```
persist security info=True;Integrated Security = SSPI;
```

I also tried connecting using IIS 8,0 and worked perfectly.